# PHP: get value from JSON String?

Tags: php, json

I have a string that looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"2",
      "price":"39.99",
      "timeStamp":"1506264307167",
      "quantity":"1",
      "colours":"Green",
      "pid":"234234234"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "price":"39.99",
      "timeStamp":"1506264311757",
      "quantity":"1",
      "colours":"Blue",
      "pid":"234234234"
   }
]
```

I need to get the id from this `JSON string` using PHP.

So I tried this:

```
$details = '[
       {
          "id":"2",
          "price":"39.99",
          "timeStamp":"1506264307167",
          "quantity":"1",
          "colours":"Green",
          "pid":"234234234"
       },
       {
          "id":"2",
          "price":"39.99",
          "timeStamp":"1506264311757",
          "quantity":"1",
          "colours":"Blue",
          "pid":"234234234"
       }
    ]';

$details = json_encode($details, true);

$array = json_decode($details, true);
$oid = $array['id'];


echo $oid;
```

The code above is in a while loop so the `echo $oid` should echo the `id` 
multiple times.

anyway, the code above only prints this:

```
[
[
```

and when i look in the error log, i see this error:

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'id'
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you turning json into json?

Comment: @JohnConde, i thought that is whats needed to be able to get the value of id?

Comment: If it is already `json` then common sense dictates that you don't need to convert it into `json`

Comment: It's an array of Object, try `current($array)->id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$details = '[
       {
          "id":"2",
          "price":"39.99",
          "timeStamp":"1506264307167",
          "quantity":"1",
          "colours":"Green",
          "pid":"234234234"
       },
       {
          "id":"2",
          "price":"39.99",
          "timeStamp":"1506264311757",
          "quantity":"1",
          "colours":"Blue",
          "pid":"234234234"
       }
    ]';


$array = json_decode($details, true);

for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $idValue = $array[$i]['id'];
    echo $idValue;
}
```

You need a loop to go through all the nested arrays and get all the ids.

Comment: Just for knowledge sake, since `foreach()` take care of indexes itself so prefer it over to `for()` as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
<?php
$details = '[
       {
          "id":"2",
          "price":"39.99",
          "timeStamp":"1506264307167",
          "quantity":"1",
          "colours":"Green",
          "pid":"234234234"
       },
       {
          "id":"2",
          "price":"39.99",
          "timeStamp":"1506264311757",
          "quantity":"1",
          "colours":"Blue",
          "pid":"234234234"
       }
    ]';


$array = json_decode($details, true);
$oid = $array[0]['id'];


echo $oid;
```

Instead of encoding `json` string into `json`. Decode it to PHP array directly. And use `[0]` index to get first `Json Object`